# How to do 'or' matching but not capture the 'or' part in a regex?

Tags: ruby, regex

I am looking for a regex which can match both the date strings. I am having trouble with specifying the 'or' expression: `/\d{4}-\d{2}-(XX|\d{2})/` doesn't work as it returns only the XX part:

```
"2007-01-XX 2008-01-01".scan(/\d{4}-\d{2}-XX/)
["2007-01-XX"]

"2007-01-XX 2008-01-01".scan(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/)
["2008-01-01"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a non-capturing group of the form `(?:...)` instead of a capturing group of the form `(...)`. So:

```
"2007-01-XX 2008-01-01".scan(/\d{4}-\d{2}-(?:XX|\d{2})/)
```

Comment: Indeed, you are correct. Updated the title to better represent the issue ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
"2007-01-XX 2008-01-01".scan(/(\d{4}-\d{2}-(XX|\d{2}))/).map(&:first)
```